# Using Capybara finder on HTML block

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

I had my Selenium tests navigating to a public dummy inbox to verify receipt of email deliveries and would perform some confirmation workflows there (password change, etc).  It was becoming far too slow and unreliable.

I'm now using the API of a mail service to retrieve an email message.  I'm able to search for the message I need and I'm able to retrieve the block of HTML that I'm usually inspecting.

Is there a way to use a Capybara finder on a block of HTML text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn a string of html into something Capybara can work with by doing

```
node = Capybara.string(the_html.to_s)
```

then you can call finders on node

node.find(...)

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!  I was starting to look at Nokogiri but this seems to work better for me.

Comment: @Phil  Technically it is using Nokogiri internally

Comment: Thanks Tom! That's helpful to know.